# I got an error message says syntax error when I use end = ", " in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
print(player_cards[card], end = ", ")
```

And this is the error message I got:

```
File "--------", line 97
print(player_cards[card], end = ", ")
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It works perfectly in Pycharm and IDLE, I got this message only when I run it in terminal(Mac)

Comment: You're either using Python 2 in the terminal, or you have a problem on the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the terminal, do:

```
python --version
```

Compare it to the other versions.

I suspect you are running python 2 in the terminal. In that case, run the appropriate python version in the terminal, and it will work just as well.

Comment: It says "Python 2.7.10", so how do I change it to 3.x?

Comment: Have you tried starting it with `python -3`?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. You need to know where you installed your python 3, and run that binary. Otherwise (better) use a virtual environment manager.

Comment: I used "python3" + file path and it works. Thanks :D

Comment: Cool, glad it worked :)